# Ping is (LSSR) not working as it should

Tags: networking, routing, ping, traceroute

when trying to reach google from my PC, here's the trace route:

[image: click_here]

But when trying to use loose source routing ping, it always return "**Request timed out**."

*ping -j 130.43.32.33 google.com (returns, Request timed out.)*

and when I'm trying something like this, (192.168.1.1 is my router private ip and 192.168.1.3 is my PC private IP):

[image: click_here]

Please help me understand this whole thing about loose and strict source routing. (kindly provide examples)

Answer (score 0):

#### Please help me understand this whole thing about loose and strict source routing

The idea behind Loose Source Routing (LSR) is to specify a [Loose Source Route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_Source_Routing), which specifies a system through which the packets **must** pass through before proceeding on to their destination.

Unfortunately, source routing has a great potential for abuse, and therefore most network administrators block all source-routed packets at their border routers.

So, in practice, Loose Source Routes aren't going to work.

```
ping -j 130.43.32.33 google.com 
Request timed out
```

This probably fails because  the owner of 130.43.32.33 has balocked source-routed packets (see above).

```
ping -j google.com 192.168.1.3
Bad route specified for loose source route.
```

This command won't work because you have the destination address **before** the intermediate destinations.

The following command **might** work, assuming source-routed packets are not blocked.

```
ping -j 192.168.1.3 google.com
```